# concatenate a column value for several rows based on condition

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which has format like this (id is the pk)

```
id|timestamps         |year|month|day|groups_ids|status |SCHEDULED          |uid|
--|-------------------|----|-----|---|----------|-------|-------------------|---|
 1|2021-02-04 17:18:24|2020|    8|  9|         1|OK     |2020-08-09 00:00:00|  1|
 2|2021-02-04 17:18:09|2020|    9|  9|         1|OK     |2020-09-09 00:00:00|  1|
 3|2021-02-04 17:19:51|2020|   10|  9|         1|HOLD   |2020-10-09 00:00:00|  1|
 4|2021-02-04 17:19:04|2020|   10| 10|         2|HOLD   |2020-10-09 00:00:00|  1|
 5|2021-02-04 17:18:30|2020|   10| 11|         2|HOLD   |2020-10-09 00:00:00|  1|
 6|2021-02-04 17:18:57|2020|   10| 12|         2|OK     |2020-10-09 00:00:00|  1|
 7|2021-02-04 17:18:24|2020|    8|  9|         1|HOLD   |2020-08-09 00:00:00|  2|
 8|2021-02-04 17:18:09|2020|    9|  9|         2|HOLD   |2020-09-09 00:00:00|  2|
 9|2021-02-04 17:19:51|2020|   10|  9|         2|HOLD   |2020-10-09 00:00:00|  2|
10|2021-02-04 17:19:04|2020|   10| 10|         2|HOLD   |2020-10-09 00:00:00|  2|
11|2021-02-04 17:18:30|2020|   10| 11|         2|HOLD   |2020-10-09 00:00:00|  2|
12|2021-02-04 17:18:57|2020|   10| 12|         2|HOLD   |2020-10-09 00:00:00|  2|
```

the job is i want to extract every group_ids for each uid when the status is OK order by SCHEDULED ascended, and if there's no OK found in the record for the uid it will takes for the latest HOLD based on year month and day. After that I want to make a weighing score with each group_ids:

```
group_ids > score
1 > 100
2 > 80
3 > 60
4 > 50
5 > 10
6 > 50
7 > 0
```

so if [1,1,2] will be change to (100+100+80) = 280
it will look like this:

```
ids|uid|pattern|score|
---|---|-------|-----|
  1|  1|[1,1,2]|  280|
  2|  2|[2]    |   80|
```

It's pretty hard since i cannot found any operators like python for loop and append operators in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6ca4f98d7448fd9a5aabdff3d01614df)

```
SELECT 
    s.uid, s.values,
    sum(v.value) as score
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (uid)
        uid,
        CASE 
            WHEN cardinality(ok_count) > 0 THEN ok_count
            ELSE ARRAY[last_value]
        END as values
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            *,
            ARRAY_AGG(groups_ids) FILTER (WHERE status = 'OK') OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY scheduled)as ok_count,
            first_value(groups_ids) OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY year, month DESC) as last_value
        FROM mytable
    ) s
    ORDER BY uid, scheduled DESC
) s,
  unnest(values) as u_group_id
  JOIN (VALUES 
      (1, 100), (2, 80), (3, 60), (4, 50), (5,10), (6, 50), (7, 0)
  ) v(group_id, value) ON v.group_id = u_group_id 
GROUP BY s.uid, s.values
```

Phew... quite complex. Let's have a look at the steps:

**a)**

```
SELECT 
    *,
    -- 1:
    ARRAY_AGG(groups_ids) FILTER (WHERE status = 'OK') OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY scheduled)as oks,
    -- 2:
    first_value(groups_ids) OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY year, month DESC) as last_value
FROM mytable
```

1. Using the [`array_agg()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) to create an array of group_ids without loosing the other data as we would with simple `GROUP BY`. The `FILTER` clause is to put only the status = OK records into the array.
2. Find the last group_id of a group (partition) using the `first_value()` window function. In descending order is returns the last value.

**b)**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (uid)                               -- 2
    uid,
    CASE                                               -- 1
        WHEN cardinality(ok_count) > 0 THEN ok_count
        ELSE ARRAY[last_value]
    END as values
FROM (
    ...
) s
ORDER BY uid, scheduled DESC                           -- 2
```

1. The `CASE` clause either takes the previously created array (from step *a1*) or, if there is none, it takes the last value (from step *a2*), creates an one-elemented array.
2. The `DISTINCT ON` clause returns only the first element of an ordered group. The group is your `uid` and the order is given by the column `scheduled`. Since you don't want the first, but last records within the group, you have to order it `DESC` to make the most recent one the topmost record. That is taken by the `DISTINCT ON`

**c)**

```
SELECT 
    uid,
    group_id
FROM (
    ...
) s,
  unnest(values) as group_id   -- 1
```

1. The arrays should be extracted into one record per element. That helps to join the weighted values later.

**d)**

```
SELECT 
    s.uid, s.values,
    sum(v.weighted_value) as score                             -- 2
FROM (
    ...
) s,
  unnest(values) as u_group_id
  JOIN (VALUES 
      (1, 100), (2, 80), ...
  ) v(group_id, weighted_value) ON v.group_id = u_group_id     -- 1
GROUP BY s.uid, s.values                              -- 2
```

1. Join your weighted value on the array elements. Naturally, this can be a table or query or whatever.
2. Regroup the `uid` groups to calculate the `SUM()` of the `weighted_value`s

---

**Additional note:**

You should avoid duplicate data storing. You don't need to store the date parts `year`, `month` and `day` if you also store the complete date. You can always calculate them from the date.

Comment: whoa very helpful @S-Man, I've tried this and works as same as i expected. Thanks