# unnest array value and count the number of occurence of each value

Tags: postgresql

The original question are based on my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66058649/concatenate-a-column-value-for-several-rows-based-on-condition/66059320#66059320)

But as i have found there is [an K-Means algorithm application for PostgreSQL](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/how-to-run-a-clustering-algorithm-within-postgresql/), i decided to  rather weighing the score to count the number of occurance of each value in the array

so if the previous result look like this

```
ids|uid|pattern|score|
---|---|-------|-----|
  1|  1|[1,1,2]|  280|
  2|  2|[2]    |   80|
```

the result must be count of each pattern but i want to keep the score empty since the score are the result from the K-Means alghorithm

```
ids|uid|pattern|b1|b2|b3|b4|b5|b6|b7|score|
---|---|-------|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|-----|
  1|  1|[1,1,2]| 2| 1| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0|     |
  2|  2|[2]    | 0| 1| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0|     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7575845a744ef245397d51cea8ff6fff)

I took [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66059320/3984221) from your linked question.

Essentially you have to replace the part for the `SUM()` with a conditional `COUNT()` using either `FILTER` or a `CASE` clause:

```
SELECT 
    uid,
    values,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE group_id = 1) as b1,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE group_id = 2) as b2,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE group_id = 3) as b3,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE group_id = 4) as b4,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE group_id = 5) as b5,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE group_id = 6) as b6,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE group_id = 7) as b7
FROM (
    -- step (b) in linked answer
) s,
  unnest(values) as group_id
GROUP BY uid, values
```

Please note: It is **NOT** simply possible to generate an arbitrary number of columns, so you need to know how many score groups are available.

Comment: i want to make the column b1 to b7 as  my feature to the K-Means algorithm and i have know that there's only 7 group_id.